# Another way to remove special characters in JSP/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Remove special characters string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747470/javascript-remove-special-characters-string-not-working)

I am trying to remove special characters that are in dynamically populated values being sent to Google Analytics; the ' in some products like "Matt's" are causing JS errors.

This is especially challenging for me because I don't really understand JavaScript or JSP. I have the following code written, but it does not achieve the desired results. Is there another way to do this? I have to modify this for Custom Variables and for _trackEvent calls directly in the anchor tags.  Below is the code for custom variables:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function removeSplChars(inStr) {
                inStr = inStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
                return inStr;
                }
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<c:out value="${profileId}"/>']);
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${(lastCmdName eq 'CategoryDisplay') or (lastCmdName eq 'ProductDisplay')}" >
                _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
                2, // This custom var is set to slot #2.
                '<c:choose><c:when test="${WCParam.source eq 'search'}">Search</c:when><c:otherwise><c:out value="${topCat}" /></c:otherwise></c:choose>', // The top-level name for your online content categories.
                '<c:choose><c:when test="${WCParam.source eq 'search'}">Search <c:out value="${WCParam.searchTerm}" /></c:when><c:otherwise><c:out value="${topCat}" />|<c:out value="${subCatA}" />|<c:out value="${subCatB}" />|<c:out value="${subCatC}" /></c:otherwise></c:choose>', // Records value of breadcrumb name
                3 // Sets the scope to page-level.
                ]); 
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                removeSplChars('<c:out value="${topCat}" />', '<c:out value="${subCatA}" />', '<c:out value="${subCatB}" />', '<c:out value="${subCatC}" />');
                 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
                (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
                </script>
```

To give an example, in the line that is commented with  *// Records value of breadcrumb name* Google is outputting the code like this:
[2,Kitchen Tools,Kitchen Tools|Textiles|Chef& # 0 3 9 ; s Apron|,3]" (without spaces between the symbols of course)

and what I am looking for is
[2,Kitchen Tools,Kitchen Tools|Textiles|Chefs Apron|,3]"

I have tried adding escapeXml="false" to the  statement but that gives me an "unexpected identifier" error with no details.

Now, I have also tried the code below. I would expect it to replace special characters with test, but nothing happens.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:out value="${jspStoreImgDir}javascript/Util.js"/>">
                    String.prototype.unescapeHtml = function () {
                        var temp = document.createElement("li");
                        temp.innerHTML = this;
                        var result = temp.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
                        return result;}
                    '<c:out value="${catNameDisplay}" />'.unescapeHtml().replace((/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, 'test');

                    </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have been working on this all day and can't find a solution.

Comment: Please clean up the code a bit before submission, and maybe only paste the parts that are relevant.

Comment: Also, write/paste the error too

Comment: if your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747470/javascript-remove-special-characters-string-not-working) does not get you the answer you were looking for, you should try to improve that question rather than reposting it as a new question.

Comment: @jbabey, thank you for pointing that out. i've made a teeny bit of progress since that was posted so i thought i should create a new question rather than rephrase what people had already responded to? I guess it's better to just update the initial question. I will do that next to so as nut to clutter up the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the previous answer was stupid. I apologize. It should've done the exact opposite.

One thing that i've noticed here is that you might be passing in multiple arguments to the `removeSplChars` method. The way the function is structured, it'll only fix the first string.

Also.. the 'fixed' string is being returned, whereas you're assuming it'll be fixed inline

you're doing something like:

```
removeSplChars(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

and expecting that `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, and `arg4` are fixed, whereas, they're not. better is:

```
arg1 = removeSplChars(arg1);
arg2 = removeSplChars(arg2);
arg3 = removeSplChars(arg3);
arg4 = removeSplChars(arg4);
```

Ok, so this 'should' fix your problems. Have fun!

Comment: There isn't an error message that's coming up - it's just not removing the special characters...I added the ' but it's still coming up. Editing my post to provide more details.

Comment: I updated the code, replacing arg1, arg2, arg3 with my <c:out /> statements. No luck.

Comment: I've been trying to edit this post so that it works, but I think there are more problems with this code than just javascript. I think you might not want to add the </c> stuff within a string. I think you're calling the `removeSplChars` after you're really using the variables. I think you're not saving the results as I said to any javascript variable, instead writing <c> stuff in the return variables area. I think you should read a bit more about what you're doing before you go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be escaped like so:

`<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
${fn:escapeXml(myString)}`

Comment: will this remove the special characters? updated my question to be more specific that i want to remove rather than replace them.

Comment: ... ahhh, no, it would not, it would just escape them.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.unescapeHtml = function () {
    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.innerHTML = this;
    var result = temp.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
    return result;
}

'&#039'.unescapeHtml().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/gi, '');
```

I got the unescapeHtml code from http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2008/09/20/javascript-how-to-unescape-html-entities/ and applied a regex to remove the special character after unescaping it.

Try it out. Just replace the string I let there for your variable.

Comment: This produces some results, I feel like I'm finally getting close! It still is not replacing the code within the gA tags though, but it is recognizing what I am looking for.  However 'Chef&#039;s'.unescapeHtml.replace.... is still producing Chef's within the GA tag. It having trouble because the GA tag is also javascript?

Comment: also, is there a way to update the code so that it can be applied to values within javascript, not within an element (up there it applies to a div, i  modified for an <li>). if you look at the code i pasted above, there are no elements in there, it's all just javascript.